# Perform a call to a function that will print character

Tags: c

The `vga_puts` function should print out characters one by one. To do so, it should perform calls to the vga_putc() function that will actually print each character.

```
void vga_putc(char c) {

  switch (c) {
  case VGA_TAB:

    vga_set_c(0x20);
    vga_incrementpos();
    vga_set_c(0x20);
    vga_incrementpos();
    vga_set_c(0x20);
    vga_incrementpos();
    vga_set_c(0x20);
    vga_incrementpos();

    break;

  case VGA_RETURN:

    pos_x = 0;

    break;

  case VGA_NEWLINE:

    pos_x = 0;
    pos_y++;

    break;

  case VGA_BACKSPACE:

    if (pos_x == 0) {
      vga_set_xy(79, pos_y--);
    }
    else if (pos_x != 0 && pos_y != 0) {
      pos_x--;
    }
    else if (pos_y == 0) {
      vga_set_xy(pos_x, pos_y);
      break;
    }
  }


  void vga_puts(char* s) {

  }
```

I understand that `vga_puts(char *s)` has a pointer to character `s` however I dont understand how to call `vga_putc(char c)` in order to print it to the screen. I tend to overthink things and I feel like its fairly simple.

Comment: You can send a literal character `'a'`, `'b'`, etc.. or any character within a string, e.g. `char str[] = "abc";` and use `str[0]` to `str[2]` to pass the character.

Comment: You should probably spend some time with a C tutorial wrt string handling.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly simple.

You probably just want this:

```
void vga_puts(char* s) {
  char c;
  while (c = *s++)  // repeat until c is 0
    vga_putc(c);
}
...
int main(void)
{
  vga_puts("Hello\r\nWorld!");
}
```

This should print this:

```
Hello
World!
```

But there are also a problems in `vga_putc`: you don't handle the case where `c` is just a normal character that should be printed, and the final `}` is missing.

The end of `vga_putc` should look like this:

```
    ...
    case VGA_BACKSPACE:

      if (pos_x == 0) {
        vga_set_xy(79, pos_y--);
      }
      else if (pos_x != 0 && pos_y != 0) {
        pos_x--;
      }
      else if (pos_y == 0) {
        vga_set_xy(pos_x, pos_y);
        break;
     }

    default:   // handle all other cases, IOW prints the characters

      vga_set_c(c);
      vga_incrementpos();
    }
  }
}   // this '}' was missing
```